# Output overwrites previous entry in file

Tags: file, powershell

If I get rid of the last line `Out-File "HDDresults.txt"` then the output shows on the screen in the correct format, just a long list of all the computers and their serial numbers. If I try to output to a file, each computer entry overwrites the previous entry, so when the script finishes executing there is only the last entry in the file. How do I get the file output to look exactly like the console output?

I don't know how to script. I just copied and pasted from multiple sources until I got something that works.

```powershell
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADComputer -filter * | Foreach-Object { 
   Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMedia -computer $_.name |
   Format-Table __server, Tag, SerialNumber |   
   Out-File "HDDresults.txt"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to set the [`-Append` flag](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849882.aspx):

```powershell
Out-File "HDDresults.txt" -Append
```

By default, `Out-File` overwrites the content of the file for each write operation.  This will cause it to add text to the end of the file instead.

Answer (score 0):

While adding the `-Append` argument makes the script function, I think a better fix to this is to move the `Select` statement and all that follows it outside of the `ForEach` loop so that the file is written once with all of the information once it is processed, and not having to open the file, write to it, close it, open it again, write to it, close it again, for each system.

```psh
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADComputer -filter * | 
   Foreach-Object { Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMedia -computer $_.name } |
   Format-Table __server, Tag, SerialNumber |   
   Out-File "HDDresults.txt"
```